# Multiple "1 line >ed" messages

Tags: command-line, indentation

When I perform multiple shift `:>` operations, vim shows me a notification for each line that's shifted. Is there a way to avoid these multiple notifications?

For example, I'm currently editing a file that's about 200,000 lines long.  About 99% of the lines contain the pattern "4111".  (The specific numbers and string aren't important.) I want to shift all the lines containing "4111" to the right using the `:>` command.

When I type:

```
:g/1444/>
```

I get a notification for each affected line:

```
1 line >ed 1 time
1 line >ed 1 time
1 line >ed 1 time
1 line >ed 1 time
1 line >ed 1 time
...
```

I would have to type <space> several thousand times to dismiss all the notifications.

By contrast, if I instead use a substitution command to achieve the same effect:

```
:g/4111/s/^/    /
```

(I have `set shiftwidth=4`) it performs all the substitutions in a couple of seconds and prints:

```
208295 substitutions on 208295 lines
```

As you can see I have a workaround, but is there a way to use the `:>` command on multiple lines and not have to dismiss notifications for each affected line?

I see this problem with vim 8.2 and 9.0. I've seen it before with other versions. (I think it's a bug in vim, which I'll report after getting some feedback here.)

Comment: The former commands runs one `:>` for each matching line. There may be a shortmess flag you can use to silence it, or use `:silent >`. Otherwise I would try pressing `:` or Esc instead of Space for the messages.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble If I press `:` or Esc, it stops shifting. `:silent g/4111/>/>` works, but it's annoying to type that every time. Do you know of some rationale for why `>` is more verbose than `s`?

Comment: You could also do `g/4111/norm >>`

Comment: `:verbose set report?`

Comment: Apparently, this is due to your personal (mis-)configuration.

Comment: @Matt That's it. I have `set report=0` in my `.vimrc`. Changing it to `2` avoids the problem. Post an answer and I'll accept it. (I still think it's at least a misfeature. Some `:` commands create a report for each affected line (`:<`, `:>`, `:y`); others don't (`:s`, `:d`).

Comment: I should have tried `vim -i NONE` before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The messages are due to custom `:h 'report'` option setting. Just keep it set to default `set report&`.

Comment: To be precise, I had `set report=0` in my `.vimrc`. Commenting out that line corrected the problem.